# An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The "yml~" translation loader is not registered.")

Tags: symfony, translation

I have this problem, when I try to load page after installed LexikTranslationBundle

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The
>   "yml~" translation loader is not registered.") in
>   backendLayoutBundle:Layout:empty.html.twig at line 8.

empty.html.twig at line 8:

> {% trans %}Reporting application{% endtrans %}

config:

```
lexik_translation:
    fallback_locale: en      # (required) default locale to use
    managed_locales: [en]    # (required) locales that the bundle have to manage
    base_layout:     "LexikTranslationBundle::layout.html.twig" # layout used with the translation edition template
    use_yml_tree:    false    # if "true" we will print a nice tree in the yml source files. It is a little slower.
    grid_input_type: text     # define field type used in the grid (text|textarea)
    storage:
        type: orm                    # where to store translations: "orm", "mongodb" or "propel"
        object_manager: default    # The name of the entity / document manager which uses different connection (see: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html)
                                     # When using propel, this can be used to specify the propel connection name
    resources_registration:
        type:                 all     # resources type to register: "all", "files" or "database"
        managed_locales_only: true    # will only load resources for managed locales
```

Comment: Do you have any actual files with translations in resources dir? And which Symfony version are you running?

Comment: Yes, I have. Symfony 2.6

Comment: For anyone looking for the answer, @MaxLipsky actually found the answer which is set the `resources_registration:` `type:` to `database`. Source: https://github.com/lexik/LexikTranslationBundle/issues/132